# Why -t release don't downgrade the package while package/release does?

Tags: apt

When upgrading a package, `-t` or `--default-release` works wonder:

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get install -t unstable libpam-gnome-keyring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpam-gnome-keyring
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 376 not upgraded.
Need to get 284 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22.5 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 268717 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-gnome-keyring_3.12.0-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-gnome-keyring (3.12.0-2) over (3.8.2-2+b1) ...
Setting up libpam-gnome-keyring (3.12.0-2) ...
```

But when I try to use it to downgrade it doesn't at all:

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get install -t testing libpam-gnome-keyring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpam-gnome-keyring is already the newest version. ## Why???
libpam-gnome-keyring set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
```

The only way is to do it is using the `package/target_release` method:

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get install libpam-gnome-keyring/testing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '3.8.2-2+b1' (Debian:testing [i386]) for 'libpam-gnome-keyring'
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libpam-gnome-keyring
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 272 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: warning: downgrading libpam-gnome-keyring from 3.12.0-2 to 3.8.2-2+b1
(Reading database ... 268716 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-gnome-keyring_3.8.2-2+b1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-gnome-keyring (3.8.2-2+b1) over (3.12.0-2) ...
Setting up libpam-gnome-keyring (3.8.2-2+b1) ...
```

Why doesn't `-t` downgrade packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-t` option just remove the pinning preferences of apt, and sets the selected release with a 990 priority, the equivalent to this:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing # for testing
Pin-Priority: 900
```

This priority isn't enough to force a package downgrade. To force a package downgrade you need 1000 or more priority for the release you are trying to downgrade to, or -1 or less on the package which version comes from the release that you want to remove.

`package/release` does something totally different. It selects the latest version in the archive of the package, in case there's more than one, and install only that package. The equivalent to:

```
apt-get download package=version
dpkg -i --force-downgrade package.deb
```

In summary, both `-t` and `package/release` follow different procedure, and the only commands capable of downgrading packages from apt are the explicit version selectors: `package=version` and `package/release`.

Comment: I think package/release temporarily sets the package to 500, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @FaheemMitha there isn't anything that suggest it does in the man page, nor sources.

Comment: Well, the sources are the definitive, er, source of information.